# Is there a Cisco IOS command that will show DIMM info per slot?

Tags: cisco, command-line-interface, memory, ios

I have a Cisco 2811 with 256MB DRAM.  I know this because `show version` tells me so.  I want to upgrade it to 768MB.  I know that this takes 1 - 512MB amd 1 - 256MB DIMM.  I know that the 2811 has 2 memory slots.

**What I do not know is whether the 256 MB I have is 2 - 128MB DIMMs or 1 - 256MB DIMM.**

Is there an IOS command for me to find this out, and if so what is it?   I am not near the router right now, so simply powering it off and removing the lid is a non-starter, however easy it would be, and let us just say that the less access the on-site staff have to the inside of my routers, the happier I'll be.  Am I doomed to drive over after hours, or else buy an additional ridiculously expensive DIMM I may not need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`show platform` gives what you want. And it's included in a show tech.

sample output (interesting part only):

```
r01#sh platform 
3725 Network IO Interrupt Throttling:
throttle count=0, timer count=0
active=0, configured=0
netint usec=4000, netint mask usec=1000
IO Mask is 3
3725,  r4k_cpu_level: 0
r4k_cpu_level: 0
Intr Mask is 9703

<snip>

Dimm 0 SPD data :
Size of dimm                 = 128 Megabytes
<snip>

Dimm 1 SPD data :
Memory Slot Empty
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.  I knew there had to be a way.

Answer (score 0):

It's late here so I can't check, could be wrong but won't `show tech-support` do that?